# css 3D rotate not working on safari and ios safari (did use -webkit- and everything)

Tags: html, css, safari, rotation, mobile-safari

I use css 3D rotate to flip the picture, it works great on Chrome and Firefox.
But when using safari, while the picture flip to the back side, it just flash and disappeared.

I already use -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden  and -webkit-transform.

I've also tried to fix it by adding -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden to the container (.inner) of front and back pictures as well. This makes the picture sticks but the buttons freeze too.

How could I fix it?

[To see the question clearly, please open in safari:](https://codepen.io/KookyMonster/pen/ExKmgZx?editors=0110)

HTML:

```
<div class="us"> <h2 id="NorthAmerica" class="usTitle"><a href="#">rotate</a></h2>
        <div class="tags">
          <!--tag1-->
          <div class="flip-card">
            <section class="tag inner">
              <div class="tag front">
                <div class="r1 ">
                  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img18/home/journeys/OTJmY2FmYTAt/OTJmY2FmYTAt-ZGUyZWFmODIt-w758._SY608_CB408650445_.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div><!--front-->

              <div class="back ny pop">
                <div class="back"></div>
                <div class="popup"></div>
                <!-- <img class="back" src="jfk.JPG" alt="NY"> -->
                <a>
                  <button class="truthButton">Ok</button>
                </a>
                <a>
                  <button class="flipButton">No</button>
                </a>
              </div> <!--back-->
             
            </section> <!--tag inner-->
           </div> <!--flip-card-->
          <div>
```

CSS:

```
/*==============
       Flip card   
===============*/
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
  
  .inner {    /*also tag*/
    position: relative;
    /* 
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            transform 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0 black;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0 black;
  }
  
  .flip-card:hover .inner {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  .front, .back {
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
    /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d; */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    width: 20em;
    height: 15em;
    background-position: center; /* Center the image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
    background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
  }

  .flipButton{
    bottom: 3%;
    right: 20%;
  }
  .truthButton{
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 20%;
  }
  .flipButton,
  .truthButton{
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--clr-pink);
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-blue);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: .2em .3em;
    font-size: var(--fs-body);
    background-color: var(--clr-blue);;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    transition: transform 0.6s; 
  }
  .truthButton::after,
  .flipButton::after {
      content: 'K';
      font-size: .1em;
      color: var(--clr-blue);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
  }
  .truthButton:hover,
  .flipButton:hover {
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    background:var(--clr-pink);
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-pink);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  /*==============
           HEADER
    ===============*/
  header {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .title a {
    font-size: var(--fs-h2);
  }
  
  .title,
  .usTitle,
  li,
  p {
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    text-align: center;
    /* font-weight: 700; */
  }
  p{
    font-size: var(--fs-h3);
  }
  .usTitle {
    font-size: var(--fs-h2);
  }
  
  li {
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-blue);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin: .5em 0;
  }
  
  li:hover {
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-pink);
    /* background: var(--clr-pink); */
  }
  
  a {
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    font-size: var(--fs-h3);
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-pink);
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    header {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    nav {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
    }
    li {
      padding: .5em;
      margin: .5em;
    }
  }
  
  /*==============
           TAGS
    ===============*/
  .tags {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    /*space-evenly*/
  }
  
  /*==============
           TAG
    ===============*/
  .r4 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .r4 .number {
    margin-right: 3em;
  }
  
  .r4 .date {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .r6 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  .r1 img {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 18em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /*compare to position absolute this is better solution to position skyteam*/
  .tag {
    /* position: relative; */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 20em;
    height: 15em;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
        align-content: center;
    background: #fff;
    /* background:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/01/14/14/white-2565766__480.jpg"); */
    -ms-grid-rows: (0.3fr)[8];
        grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 0.3fr);
        grid-template-areas: "r1" "r2" "r3" "r4" "." "r6" "r7" "r8";

    /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; */
  }
  
 
  /*==============
           BASE
    ===============*/
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  :root {
    --clr-dark: #232323;
    --clr-pink: #ff3385;
    --clr-blue: #80d4ff;
    --ff-main: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    --fs-h1: 3rem;
    --fs-h2: 2.5rem;
    --fs-h3: 1.8rem;
    --fs-body: 1.25rem;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    background: #232323;
    font-family: var(0ff-main);
  }
  
  a,
  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    :root {
      --fs-h1: 1.5rem;
      --fs-h2: 1.25rem;
      --fs-h3: .8rem;
      --fs-body: 0.25rem;
    }
  }
  .ny{
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/28/13/09/usa-1777986__480.jpg);
  }
```